# Achartengine graph not displaying initially

Tags: android, achartengine

Right now I'm using aChartEngine library in my Android project.  It's working nicely so far.  One thing I can't figure out is how to get it initially displayed. The only way to show my data is to click and pan somewhere on the graph or press the zoom buttons.  So the zoom buttons are initially displayed, but not the graph itself.  I searched through the methods for the renderer, but nothing worked.  I call `mSeriesRenderer.setShowGrid(true);` after my renderer is created and it doesn't display.  I've also tried to `repaint()` and not even that is working.  Am I calling it at the wrong time?

```
public void onResume()
{
    if(mMeterObs.getGraph() == null)
    {
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.chart);
        mMeterObs.setGraph(ChartFactory.getLineChartView(this, mMeterObs.getMultipleSeries(), mMeterObs.getSeriesRenderer()));
        layout.addView(mMeterObs.getGraph(), LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        mMeterObs.repaint();
    }
    else
        mMeterObs.repaint();
}
```

`mMeterObs.getMultipleSeries()` and `mMeterObs.getSeriesRenderer()` are both empty to begin with, but it should still be able to display the grid and axes, right?

In the constructor for `mMeterObs` I call this:

```
mSeriesRenderer.setXLabels(12);
    mSeriesRenderer.setYLabels(10);
    mSeriesRenderer.setShowGrid(true);
    mSeriesRenderer.setXLabelsAlign(Align.RIGHT);
    mSeriesRenderer.setYLabelsAlign(Align.RIGHT);
    mSeriesRenderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(true);
    mSeriesRenderer.setRange(new double[] { 0.0, 10.0, -1.0, 1.0 });
    //mSeriesRenderer.setPanEnabled(true);
    mSeriesRenderer.setZoomLimits(new double[] { -10, 20, -10, 40 });
    mSeriesRenderer.setGridColor(Color.LTGRAY);
    mSeriesRenderer.setShowGrid(true);
    mSeriesRenderer.setShowAxes(true);
    mSeriesRenderer.setPointSize(.5f);
```

Comment: The condition `if(mMeterObs.getGraph() == null)` looks suspect. Why not call `layout.addView()` in `onCreate()` instead of `onResume()`?

Comment: Also implement `mMeterObs.getMultipleSeries()` and `mMeterObs.getSeriesRenderer()` FWIW.

Comment: I had it like that initially, but one of the SO questions I found suggested to put it in onResume().  What do you mean with your second comment?

Comment: If the `LinearLayout` is in a `ScrollView`, you have to call `renderer.setInScroll(true);`. Also fill the chart with some values to begin with and check.

Comment: `LinearLayout` is the root view.  I'm fairly certain that I've narrowed the problem down to the XYSeries not having any data until I start collecting it.  Was hoping that there was a workaround. :\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you add some series with data.
Grids are only displayed along the labels, but you have no labels.

Comment: Well I'm hoping to have it displayed initially so that the user knows a graph is available, and then let the user add data sources to the graph.  So it starts out with no series of data and then the user adds whatever they want.  Seems weird that I can't display the empty grid without having a series of data.

Comment: Have you tried the demo program that ACE provides? If you start it and select "Embedded line chart demo", you will see no chart. Click on "New Series" and you will see the axes. This is because an empty series has been added. Just add an empty series and you will see the axes.

Comment: Adding a blank series worked, although now there is a blank legend entry that I'm trying to remove.  I'll mark this as correct though.

Comment: renderer.setShowLegend(false);

Comment: `XYSeriesRenderer` doesn't seem to have that method.  I just set the color to black as a quick hack and that is good enough for now. :\